# What steps should I take to format my SSD to ensure that malware is removed?

Tags: bios, ssd

Recently, I was subject to being hacked. I tried to wipe Windows and delete the old Windows files after re-installing, but I feel a rootkit was installed and hidden from Norton scans. I randomly received a Google sign-in attempt from my PC, when I was not using it (after I re-installed) which has led me to believe such.

I want to format my SSD and possibly flash my bios, if it is necessary.
How would I go about doing this?

I am currently using a Samsung 970 Evo Plus. I tried to install Samsung Magician to secure erase, but I feel as this is my primary drive, there could be issues with rebooting into an OS.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Samsung secure erase.

Answer (score 0):

This will wipe/destroy **all your data** but it's the safest method:

0. Disconnect your SSD from your PC
1. On a different **known** to be clean computer, download the latest firmware for your computer and save it to a USB flash drive.
2. From your computer, (re)flash this EFI image. This may take several reboots. Once you see "Unable to boot", power off your PC.
3. Attach your SSD back.
4. On the same **different** computer download something like https://www.system-rescue.org to any USB flash drive.
5. Go into BIOS settings and disable Secure Boot temporarily.
6. Boot from this USB flash drive but make sure your system does **not** even attempt to boot from an SSD.
7. Once you're in System Rescue, type this command (it will **completely destroy all** your SSD data):
   `blkdiscard -v -f /dev/nvme0`
8. Type `reboot`, get into BIOS, reenable Secure Boot.

Your system now has a known good EFI firmware and a completely empty SSD drive. You can now install Windows 10/11 (using the official ISO, [10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) or [11](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11)) and you should be malware free.